# Kubernetes ABAC mode not working

Tags: kubernetes, abac

I found a few people that tried to tackle this, only slightly relevant posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786244/what-username-does-the-kubernetes-kubelet-use-when-contacting-the-kubernetes-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790438/using-kubectl-with-kubernetes-authorization-mode-abac) but doesn't solve it for me.

The problem:
I want to create a read-only user for my cluster using ABAC policy.
My cluster has 3 masters and 3 workers, version 1.4.7 hosted on AWS.

I edited my manifests/apiserver.yml like so on all 3 masters (added these 3 lines - at the bottom of the file of course I mounted the relevant paths etc..):

- --token-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/policy/user-tokens.csv
- --authorization-mode=ABAC
- --authorization-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/policy/apiusers.yml

my apiuser.yml looks like this:

```
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"group": "system:authenticated", "readonly": true, "nonResourcePath": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "apiGroup": "*"}}
```

My users-token.csv looks like this:

```
tdU0ynyO3wG6UAzwWP0DO7wvF2tH8pbH,bob,bob
```

My kubeconfig file has this in it:

```
users:
- name: bob
  user:
    token: tdU0ynyO3wG6UAzwWP0DO7wvF2tH8pbH
```

When I try `kubectl get nodes` it's failing, I can print the output with --v=8 if it's relevant but it basically says `Forbidden(403)`.
It seems to me, I'm missing something fundamental here, the policy is in place and blocking everything and everyone, though it should allow authenticated users read only rights.

Any kind of help or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the `system:authenticated` group was added in 1.5

prior to 1.5, you can use `"user":"*"`

Comment: Ah Jordan I was just reading your other posts.. amazing that's what I was missing. I don't have enough credits to vote you up but that is exactly the correct solution for my exact situation.

Comment: one more question, if I want another user to be admin, that would be:
"spec": {"user": "core-admin",  "nonResourcePath": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "apiGroup": "*"}} ? and then in my kubeconfig I would set another context for the same cluster (and add username etc...) ? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I answered myself.. what I wrote above is correct, there's importance to the appearance of the policy object, i.e. the admin should be the first line.